# Upgrade Ubuntu Server from 11.04 to 11.10 without internet connection

Tags: server, upgrade, documentation

We have application software that really likes **Ubuntu Server 11.10**. I need to upgrade several 11.04 servers to this version. Two questions:

1. The servers that need to be upgraded do not have Internet access in our datacenter due to security reasons. I need to download the updates/upgrades to a secure system and then transfer them to the datacenter servers for installation. Is anyone aware of the steps involved?
2. How/where do I get the 11.10 updates from? I don't see an option on the Ubuntu site for downloading specific versions of the OS and/or upgrades.

Comment: Do they have network access? Why not create your own mirror of the repositories in the local network there (`apt-mirror`)? Then you don't need any internet connection from these machines directly.

Comment: @gertvdijk That answers the question here (about upgrading 11.04 Server to 11.10 without an Internet connection). I recommend posting this as an answer. *This is not really too localized. Asking how to upgrade to a newer release without Internet access is not an issue unlikely to appear again; I think this is likely relevant many, many people.* Also...do you happen to know if it's possible to use the Server CD to upgrade? If not, can one upgrade a Server system with the alternate CD? (I don't see why not, although these releases are old enough they probably use different kernels.)

Comment: @TonyMarciano Since you folks are very concerned about the security of the servers in your data center, does that mean you've been installing security updates as they've been released? If so, please edit your question to provide information about *how* you have been doing that, as it may be possible to upgrade in a similar way. If not, please note that being accessible only on a restricted intranet does not eliminate security considerations; by not patching vulnerabilities, you are (and have been) at serious risk. This also applies to *using* 11.04 since 28 October 2012 when it went EoL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Try installing 11.10 with a disc or making a ISO image with Brasero then installing that. with that you can select what you want on the ISO.

Hope this helps, 
bob

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade without internet access by using the "alternate" installation CD or ISO file. Read the [instructions for Ubuntu Desktop](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OneiricUpgrades#Upgrading_Using_the_Alternate_CD.2BAC8-DVD), then use this [variation for Ubuntu Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Upgrades#Upgrades_via_alternate_CD):

```
sudo ./cdromupgrade --frontend=DistUpgradeViewText
```

You can download [end of life](http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife) releases from [old-releases.ubuntu.com](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/oneiric/).